# The security of JSON-RPC

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, security, json-rpc

I currently use web3 and geth to develop dapps, and we know that web3 interacts with geth through json rpc. If we want to unlock an account through dapp, we need to enter the password in the dapp, and then web3 will unlock it through json rpc. I want to know when web3 uses the password provided by the user to send an unlock request to geth, will this password be hijacked by an intermediary? I personally think that json rpc is also transmitted in plain text, so I think json rpc is not safe, I don’t know if my understanding is correct.

Hope you can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining unlocked accounts on the node that you're communicating with is typically useful for testing your contracts on a local network, for example, via ganache.

When working on a remote network, it is generally risky because anyone hacking the node that you're communicating with can exploit those unlocked accounts at will.

So you may want to consider the following alternative scheme:

**When a user registers:**

1. The user enters a memorable password
2. The client encrypts the private key with the password, and sends it to the server
3. The server receives the encrypted private key, and saves it into the database

**When a user logs-in:**

1. The server sends the encrypted private key to the client

**When a user performs a transaction available on client's web-page:**

1. The user enters the password
2. The client decrypts the private key using the password
3. The client signs the transaction with the private key
4. The client sends the signed transaction to the server
5. The server sends the signed transaction to the node

Comment: Hi, goodvibration! Your answer helped me a lot. I am not very clear about one place. In your answer, it says: 4. The client sends the signed transaction to the server. 5. The server sends the signed transaction to the node.
I know that web3 can be used to send signed transactions to geth node. From a specific technical point of view, how to implement steps 4 and 5? Do I need to use web3 on both the client and server sides?

Comment: @weiwang: It doesn't have to be web3.js of course, but yes - if you choose to work with web3.js, then you could use:

Comment: 3. `const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txOptions, privateKey);`.

Comment: 4. Send the output of it (`signedTx.rawTransaction`) to the server via HTTP or similar.

Comment: 5. `const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);`.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer! I fully understand this problem now!

Comment: Hi, goodvibration! Excuse me again. I just thought about this question again, and I think there is a problem with my idea of using web3 on the client side. Using web3 on the client's webpage requires the geth node to open all rpccorsdomain so that the ip of the user accessing the client's webpage can access the geth node. So is it still unsafe to use web3 on the client side, which will cause ips other than the server to access the geth node?

Comment: @weiwang: "Using web3 on the client's webpage requires the geth node to open all rpccorsdomain" - why? Nothing that I mentioned for the client side (for example, signing a transaction) requires any interaction with a GETH node. In fact, I've explicitly stated that your interaction with a node should be done on the server side.

Comment: My understanding is this. In the front-end code, you may need to write:
`const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://121.23.11.231:8545");
 const web3 = new Web3(provider);`
The front-end code is executed in the user's browser, which requires the geth node with an IP address of 121.23.11.231 to allow all users' IP to access it, otherwise a web3 object cannot be generated in the user's browser.

Comment: Because I use web3 in my code now, I may analyze the problem from the perspective of web3. For example, if I want to execute `const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txOptions, privateKey);` on the front end, shouldn't the premise be that there should be a web3 object on the client web page?

I don't know if my understanding is correct?

Comment: @weiwang: "My understanding is this. In the front-end code, you may need to write..." - no you don't. `const web3 = new Web3()` should be good enough. And again - you don't even need to use web3.js. You just need to sign the transaction with the private key (obtained by decrypting it using the client's entered password), and then send that signed transaction (a hex string) to the server.

Comment: @weiwang: I might be wrong with regards to `web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction`. If that requires the web3 object to be connected to a provider, then you should use a different sign-transaction method. If I remember correctly, then web3.js has such function also under another module (but it also might be the case that you can use the one under `eth.accounts` without connecting to a provider).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will take time to study the solution you provided! Thank you again for your great help!